# How to center text vertically and horizontally in between floated button elements?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering, text-align

I have a couple of buttons in a toolbar. They are floated to the left and right to give the middle-text 100% of the remaining width. Text could be one or two rows...

My problem is that I need to center the text and position it in the middle vertically.

MARKUP

```
<div class="toolbar">
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button right">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button right">&nbsp;</div>
<span class="title">Start page title</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
    float: left;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
.toolbar{
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.button{
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #666666;
}
.title{
    font-size: 12px;   
    line-height: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I do have a fiddle as well (click a gray button to try it with dual row text):
http://jsfiddle.net/U7LhL/6/

Any ideas? Setting line height wouldn't work (unless using JS) since height of the text is unknown and i need to fit 2 lines. Using absolute positioned text to achieve this would make it pretty messy I think, if even possible.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible with `float` elements, as they don't have a chance for vertical alignment. You have to use flex layout with a fallback to `table-cell` display for older browsers.

Comment: for vertical-alignement use : line-height: 68px; on title class

Comment: did you tried line-height property and vertical-alignment to middle?

Comment: @NicolòMonili That don't work if text is 2 lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the text container display: table-cell.

```
body {
    background: pink;
}
.toolbar {
    display: table;
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.button {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    background: #4679bd url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat -6% 50%;
}
.toolbar > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.title {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.center {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/U7LhL/7/)**

Comment: @Era if he can't change the markup then he can also solve using just css.

Comment: @Era yeah I think it will not be this perfect if OP didn't change the markup. I will take my word back :)

Comment: It did work great in my code, in my case this markup change was totally fine! Brilliant... Thank you!

Comment: @JesperWilfing np.. :). please mark it as answer if my post solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

With flex you can rearrange the elements visually by setting their order (order: 1, 2, 3) and stretch the title to fill in all the space left (flex:1 1 100%;).

The property align-items:center; does the trick and aligns all the items to the center.

```css
.toolbar{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.button{
  padding:1rem;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.left{
  order:1;
}
.right{
  order:3;
}
.title{
  text-align:center;
  padding:1rem;
  order:2;
  flex:1 1 100%;
  background:beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="button left">Button</div>
  <div class="button left">Button</div>
  <div class="button left">Button</div>
  <div class="button right">Button</div>
  <div class="button right">Button</div>
  <span class="title">Start page title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try as follows. Add class for title warp.

Html Code

```
    <div class="toolbar">
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button right">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="button right">&nbsp;</div> <div class="titleWarp"> <span class="title">Start page title</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body{
    background: pink;
}
.left{
    float: left;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
.toolbar{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.button{
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #4679bd url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat -6% 50%;
}
#title{
width: 75%;
margin:0px auto;
}
.titleWarp{
    font-size: 12px;   
    line-height: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted this in my fiddle (replacing the ID tag on title). Did not see how it could work. Also the title has a fixed width here which are not desirable if adding or removing buttons...